# Wireless networks are not identified by Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have 2 Windows 7 Laptops.  One of them works fine, but the other as of a few days ago and for no apparent reason is no longer identifying any network I try to connect to.  When I turn on the wireless adapter -- a built in Realtek RTL8187B Wireless 802.11 b/g 54Mbps USB 2.0 Network Adapter -- it gives me a list of available networks.

When I click on one of them is gives me the loading bar, which shortly disappears and if I click on the bars at the bottom right of my screen it says that I am connected, but it is Identifying and I have no Internet access.  Then it stays the same for at least an hour, that is longest I have let it sit and it never changed.  It did do the Identifying before, but it always identified it after not too long and then I could do whatever with it.

I have looked on many websites, including several threads on this one, and tried many solutions -- such as re-installing the Realtek driver and using the route DELETE command -- but it still will not work.  By the way, in case I did not make it clear enough in the preceding, I am not a computer expert, so I would be much obliged if you would try to make your answers as dumbed-down as possible.  Again I have Windows 7.

Comment: Does the [event log](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Open-Event-Viewer) say something on this? If not, you might want to check `ifpconfig /all` if it has DHCP or Internet; then also look if data is sent as well as received in the connection's properties and if so do a [low level packet trace with Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org). Good luck! If all else fails, you might want to try [step 12 and 13 I posted here](http://superuser.com/questions/338320/all-my-browsers-suddenly-dont-support-javascript-files-anymore/338419#338419)...

Comment: I did not see anything in the event log.  I tried ifpconfig /all and I got the message: " 'ifpconfig' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."  I cannot connect to the internet, so I cannot download Wireshark unless I burn a disk from this computer and put it on the bad computer, but I will have to buy the disks first.  I also tried the steps in the link you provided and some of them said they were successful but I needed to restart my computer, others said that they were not recognized and/or failed to execute.  I still cannot access the Internet.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I made a typo there. It's `ipconfig /all` without the `f`. Pay notice to the IP address you received there, if it starts with 169 then DHCP is not working properly. Try manually configuring a static IP in that case... See a [detailed explanation](http://portforward.com/networking/static-win7.htm).

Comment: OK.  One line says: Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.241.99<Preferred>.  How do I set up the Static IP?

Comment: Oh, oops.  I did not see the link.

Comment: @SEVidrio: That's indeed DHCP not properly functioning; you need to figure out what the IP of the other computer is using the same command on that computer, then give your non-functioning computer an IP in the same range. So if one computer is like `192.168.1.11` you could give the other computer `192.168.1.12`...

Comment: I set up the IP address and now instead of stopping at "Identifying" it connects, but it tells me that it is an unidentified network and I still cannot access the Internet.  Also, when I bring up Internet Explorer on the bad computer I now get a message "Google Toolbar has stopped working", and if I close it, it just pops up again.  Does that mean anything?

Comment: Can you ping the router and DNS servers? Use the gateway address the other computer has as well as the DNS servers, execute `ping X.X.X.X` where you fill in `X.X.X.X` as the IP.

Comment: I typed in the command prompt: ping x (where x is the good computer's IP) and received the following message: "Reply from Y (Where Y is the bad computer's IP): Destination host unreachable."  It repeats that 4 times and then gives statistics.

Comment: But can you ping the router? I don't have any ideas anymore, you need the troubleshooting steps. You don't need a disk for that, something as cheap as a USB stick will do fine...

Comment: OK I will get a USB stick and try the Wireshark thing.  Thank you so much for continuing to try to help me for this long.