# All invalid hostnames resolve to localhost in my browser. What is going on?

Tags: windows-7, networking, browser, dns, troubleshooting

**Update:** jump to the end of this question for the happy conclusion to this epic tale.

---

Note: I have IIS7 installed locally for web development.

This is what happens in my browser for random sites:

> [image: local web server]

**That is, a *totally gibberish URL* resolves to my localhost webserver.** (All gibberish hosts do this--not just the one.)

This affects several of us in the company...but doesn't appear to affect *all* of us.

#### Here's the troubleshooting I've done so far:

1. Checked my proxy settings - all clear
2. Checked my hosts file - all clear
3. Checked other browsers - it affects Chrome, Chrome Incognito, and Internet Explorer
4. Ping/nslookup google and a random gibberish url:

   C:\Users\mharen>**ping google.com**

   Pinging google.com [74.125.228.98] with 32 bytes of data:
     Reply from 74.125.228.98: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=51
     ...

   C:\Users\mharen>**nslookup google.com**

   Server:  (my dns)
     Address:  192.168.48.20

   Non-authoritative answer:
     Name:    google.com
     Addresses:  2607:f8b0:4004:803::100e
             74.125.228.100 ... 74.125.228.98

   C:\Users\mharen>**ping somerandomsitesoaosoasda.com**

   Ping request could not find host somerandomsitesoaosoasda.com. Please check the name and try again.

   C:\Users\mharen>**nslookup somerandomsitesoaosoasda.com**

   Server:  (my dns)
     Address:  192.168.48.20
     *** (my dns) can't find somerandomsitesoaosoasda.com: Non-existent domain

So that is what I would expect--good domains resolve, bad ones don't. So what in the world is screwing with my browser?

Any troubleshooting tips?

#### Update: `ipconfig /displaydns`

I just ran `ipconfig /displaydns`, which is pretty spiffy. Here's the interesting entry among a few dozen good records:

```
somerandomsitesoaosoasda.com
----------------------------------------
Name does not exist.
```

#### Update: Try new DNS servers:

In case pinging and nslooking wasn't enough to rule out my DNS servers, I followed Joshua's suggestion and switched over to Google's DNS. Unfortunately, the problem persisted.

### Update: Fixed!

With help from the answer Joshua linked to, we determined that this command fixed the issue:

```
netsh winsock reset all
```

We ran this command before and after to see what it changed:

```
netsh winsock show catalog
```

Which revealed 10 entries like this were missing after the `reset` command was run:

```
Winsock Catalog Provider Entry
------------------------------------------------------
Entry Type:                         Layered Chain Entry
Description:                        BarracudaWSA over [MSAFD Tcpip [TCP/IP]]
Provider ID:                        {FECB95F8-BE34-4B8A-A1ED-16A678A8ACC6}
Provider Path:                      C:\windows\system32\BarracudaWSA64.dll
Catalog Entry ID:                   1017
Version:                            2
Address Family:                     2
Max Address Length:                 16
Min Address Length:                 16
Socket Type:                        1
Protocol:                           6
Service Flags:                      0x66
Protocol Chain Length:              2
Protocol Chain: 1016 : 1001
```

BarracudaWSA (Web Security Agent), it turns out, is a web filter installed by IT.

Comment: I like Joshua's suggestion of ensuring it's YOUR localhost. Just edit `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.htm`, if you don't want to disable your local IIS.

Comment: @roviuser it's definitely *my* localhost. Good idea, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some ideas:

- Are you SURE this is your localhost? Or... could it be that your DNS server is also running IIS and serving that default page for domains that do not resolve? Have you tried disabling your local IIS server?
- Also blaming the DNS server, could it be that the DNS server returns 127.0.0.1 for non-existent domains?
- Have you checked the local routes to see if anything odd appears? To view, pull up a command prompt and enter "route print".

How to test whether the DNS server is misconfigured:

1. Open your local network adapter settings, and change your IPv4 and / or IPv6 DNS settings from "Obtain DNS server address automatically" to "Use the following DNS server addresses".
2. Set the Preferred and Alternate to something else, such as Google Public DNS or Neustar's DNS Advantage:

   - https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/
   - http://www.neustar.biz/enterprise/dns-services/free-recursive-dns
3. Try the bad domains again.

---

For the win: This guy's answer (seems to have gotten you to the right place): 
[All my browsers suddenly don't support Javascript files anymore?](https://superuser.com/questions/338320/all-my-browsers-suddenly-dont-support-javascript-files-anymore?rq=1)

Congrats. Glad I could at least help steer you in the right direction :)

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue - we've determined it is localhost by renaming welcome.png in C:\inetpub\wwwroot. The page displays a broken image as expected. Disabling IIS results in a 404 error, re-enabling displays the splash screen.

Comment: @Joshua, it is definitely my localhost. I'm not sure how else to exclude your other idea-- I did pings and nslookups to random hosts and they *do not resolve.* I'm open to other ideas, though. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelHaren I updated my answer with How...

Comment: Thanks, @Joshua, I switched over to Google's DNS and the problem persisted. That's helpful in ruling out my office's and ISP's DNS.

Comment: Have you checked the local routes to see if anything odd appears? To view, pull up a command prompt and enter "route print"?

Comment: @Joshua yes, I checked that. No persistent routes. Nothing too odd...though I admit I'm not a pro at reading them.

Comment: Based on the fact that this affects high level apps (browsers) but not lower level stuff (e.g. `ping`), I'm thinking that my browsers are being highjacked by IT for webfiltering or something more nefarious.

Comment: Hmmm... check out the answer on this question: http://superuser.com/questions/338320/all-my-browsers-suddenly-dont-support-javascript-files-anymore?rq=1

Comment: @Joshua, thanks! Doing all the stuff in [step 12](http://superuser.com/a/338419/730) seems to have fixed the issue. Now I'll see if rebooting brings it back and then maybe I can narrow it down a bit more to what precisely does it. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelHaren great, glad it helped. I updated my "answer" to have the link as well, so it's a valid "answer" for what it's worth. :)